# fcopy to copy a file from host to vm using tcl

Tags: sockets, tcl, virtual-machine

i want to use tcl command fcopy to copy a file from windows host machine to a vm location. What I get is I need a inchannel and a outchannel. Here inchannel in the filestream and out channel is some kind of socket where a server is runing maybe. I am at bay regarding the server part and how the file will be saved from the socket in a vm path. Please guide with some resource link.

Answer (score 0):

If you have two filenames (and both are currently visible, which depends on how things are mounted and which is totally out of baseline Tcl's control) use `file copy`. Otherwise, if you can arrange to get the contents of the file *somehow* (perhaps by using `ssh hostaddress cat`) then you use `chan copy` (which `fcopy` is the old name for).

```
set srcFD [open |[list ssh hostaddress cat "src/file.ext"] "r"]
set dstFD [open "dst/file.ext" "w"]

chan copy $srcFD $dstFD;    # Or: fcopy $srcFD $dstFD

close $srcFD
close $dstFD
```

Comment: If you're using `ssh`, I'm assuming you've got `ssh-agent` set up already…